# The probability of getting a larger number in a specific dice

Tags: probability

Bob throws cube with the numbers 1-n 
and Alice throws cube with the numbers 1-m
It is known that $m>n$,whoever gets a bigger number wins
What's the probability Bob will win?

(I thought of that answer,but I'm not sure I'm right)

$$\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot \frac{n-1}{m},$$ [because] the good numbers for Bob are 2 to n(because 1 can never win). Alice-Out of M numbers,from n to m,not good because we want Bob to win. Then we were left with only n-1 numbers that can lose(because the n number cannot lose).

Comment: Could you please include the steps, explained, that you took to arrive at your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: yes,the good numbers for Bob are 2 to n(because 1 can never win).
Alice-Out of M numbers,from n to m,not good because we want Bob to win.
Then we were left with only n-1 numbers that can lose(because the n number cannot lose)

Comment: Why not work an example using small $n,m$?  A few examples should make it easy to decide if your proposed solution might be right.

Comment: In your case, note that if $m=n+1$ and $n$ is large, your expression is effectively $1$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really, can you explain where the mistake is?

Comment: Thanks for the information, @complex_stock; I edited your post to add the additional context you provided, there.

Answer (score 1):

$\text{P(Bob`s number is 2 and Alice`s number is 1)}=\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{1}{m}$

$\text{P(Bob`s number is 3 and Alice`s number less than 3)}=\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{2}{m}$

$\text{P(Bob`s number is 4 and Alice`s number less than 4)}=\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{3}{m}$

...

$\text{P(Bob`s number is n and Alice`s number less than n)}=\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{n-1}{m}$
$$\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{2}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{3}{m}+...+\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{n-1}{m} =$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\times(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{2}{m}+\frac{3}{m}+...+\frac{n-1}{m})=$$
$$=\frac{1}{n}\times (\frac{1+2+3+...+n-1}{m}) =$$
$$= \frac{1}{n}\times \frac{\frac{(n-1)\times n} {2}}{m} =$$
$$=\frac{n-1}{2m} $$

where $m > n$